# Laptop's network adapter connecting at 100 Mbps instead of 1 Gbps

Tags: networking, ethernet

Some weird stuff started happening with my wife's laptop. Instead of 1 Gbps she was getting before, at some point of time, she started getting 100 Mbps.
It's not a problem with router nor it is a problem with a cable. My PC is getting 1 Gbps and I tried using that cable and port on the router for laptop and it was still getting 100 Mbps. I've tried setting link speed to 1 Gbps but it didn't help either. What are other possible causes for such a problem?

Comment: Just because one device achieves a 1Gb/s link, doesn't mean that another can... signal integrity being what it is, a marginal / failed link on one device might look "_good_" on another.

Comment: If you have proven it's not the router/switch port or the cable, you only have two remaining choices... The network adapter is defective or the operating system (or a driver) is not working properly. You can test the later by downloading and booting a live Linux distro from USB and see if you get gigabit there, if not it's probably a hardware issue.

Comment: Always worth spending a fiver on some contact cleaner. Grubby contacts can do that. Don't spray whilst powered on.

Comment: @Attie You seem to have missed the part where I said she used to have 1Gbps before.

Comment: @Tetsujin hmm, quite possibly, yeah. Will try that, thanks

Comment: @IgorYavych no, things change, equipment gets old, etc... If it was marginal one day, it may not work the next (sound familiar?)

Comment: Will the laptop establish a gigabit link to something else over a different (short) cable?

Comment: @Attie tried to connect to my PC, link established was 100 Mbps. And I find it hard to believe that it went from 1Gbps to 100 Mbps with no equipment change within few months.

Comment: What happens with the laptop connected with mains and on battery... do you notice the link speed reduces whilst on battery, or both? Additionally, have you the latest drivers installed?

Comment: You failed to mention what the model number is of your wife's network adapter. It may help.

Comment: Ethernet doesn't gracefully degrade - the options are 1Gb/s or 100Mb/s, there is no inbetween.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It doesn't say exact model just "Realtek PCIE GBE Family Controller". Laptop model is Asus X550VX

Comment: @Kinnectus it's 100Mbps regardless of it being connected to network or on battery. And yes, latest drivers are installed

Comment: @acejavelin tried to boot from Debian Live CD, still 100mbps

Comment: Do you have option in the advanced settings of the network card to force 1Gbps? (No auto-negotiation) It may be worth it to try a short cat-5e or cat-6 patch cable connected to the router from the problematic PC. If it establishes a 1Gbps link on the patch cord, you know that this particular NiC has an issue with the cable in use. Also, if you have an option for "green ethernet" try disabling it, sometimes it can mis-read the total length of the pairs and improperly set the voltage on the signaling.

Comment: Check the pins in the port on the laptop... You have eliminated everything but the port and chipset on the laptop. The last remaining thing that might be repairable is the plug itself... A 10 or 100 connection only requires 4 wires (pins 1, 2, 3, 6) and gigabit requires all 8 pins/wires.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It establishes 1Gpbs, but only if I push the connector up a bit. If I let it go, it disconnects and connects back with 100Mbps. So I guess it's safe to say that the problem is with the port I guess. As for green ethernet, disabling it didn't help, but disabling energy efficient ethernet allowed it to establish 1Gbps on a longer cable (before that, it wouldn't no matter how I tried to push it up)